# Hide fixed div behind other div

Tags: html, css

Got a fixed div with a tag cloud hanging on a side of a page. It overflows footer divs. And i need it to scroll under. Can't really set a z index to -1 since it's on top of another div.
Tried setting up z-index where footer would have greater one. Didn't work. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `display:none;`?

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: I can't use display:none since it has to be displayed. I just need it to slide under footer div. Also, using a 3rd party theme, so simplifying the code is gonna take a while. Just looking for a quick hack to slide fixed div under another.

Comment: If you are looking for a quick hack, just absolute position it , and set the top and left locations to the bottom left of the div you want it under.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic but I had the same issue on my project. Z-index works... if you give the element it should scroll under a position. So let's say you have:

```
<div id="floating">I'm a cloud</div>
<footer>I'm a rock</footer>
```

Then your CSS should look something like this:

```
#floating { position: fixed; top: 100px; right: 100px; z-index: 50; }
footer { position: relative; z-index: 999; }
```